# Cluster Shared Cache 

Tags: java, caching, distributed-computing, cluster-computing

I am searching for a java framework that would allow me to share a cache between multiple JVMs.

What I would need is something like [**Hazelcast**](http://www.hazelcast.com/) but without the "distributed" part. I want to be able to add an item in the cache and have it automatically synced to the other "group member" cache. If possible, I'd like the cache to be sync'd via a reliable multicast (or something similar).

I've looked at [**Shoal**](https://shoal.dev.java.net/) but sadly the "Distributed State Cache" seems like an insufficient implementation for my needs.

I've looked at [**JBoss Cache**](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/) but it seems a little overkill for what I need to do.

I've looked at [**JGroups**](http://www.jgroups.org/), which seems to be the most promising tool for what I need to do. Does anyone have experiences with JGroups ? Preferably if it was used as a shared cache ?

Any other suggestions ?

Thanks !

**EDIT** : We're starting tests to help us decide between Hazelcast and Infinispan, I'll accept an answer soon.

**EDIT** : Due to a sudden requirements changes, we don't need a distributed map anymore. We'll be using JGroups for a low level signaling framework. Thanks everyone for you help.

Comment: Hazelcast and Infinispan?  Hmmm.   These are not mature technologies...  Try pressing Ctrl-z in the Hazelcast demo in one node.  Split brain.  Infinispan is still in alpha!  I recommend you look at http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions for a starting point.  EHCache, OSCache and JBoss Cache are at least mature well accepted technologies.  You already said Terracotta is heavyweight so that's fine.  I just hate to see you waste your time and find you've gone with something completely unstable.

Comment: We haven't decided yet, we're just testing. Thanks for your concerns Taylor :) Also, CTRL-Z in the Hazelcast demo works fine. So does killing any node via Task Manager or any other way.

Comment: Once again, Terracotta can help you here ;-).  Locking/signaling in Terracotta is incredibly easy.  Here's synchronized wait/notify across the cluster for signalling between threads in a cluster: http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Recipe?recipe=waitnotify

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some more searching, I found [**JGroup's ReplicatedHashMap**](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e1949). It has not been thoroughly tested but it seems like an excellent start. It fills all my requirements without giving me too much features I don't need. It's also quite flexible. I'm still searching for the "perfect" answer though :)

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: JBossCache is essentially an industrial-strength implementation of ReplicatedHashMap. It uses the same underlying JGroups transport mechanism.

Answer (score 13):

How about this?

Have a local ConcurrentHashMap as your local cache.
Create a Hazelcast distributed map/cache.
Start listening for the distributed map events and update your local ConcurrentHashMap.

Now local caches on each member will be the same. Auto-synched.

```
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap; 
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.EntryListener;
import com.hazelcast.core.EntryEvent; 
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Sample implements EntryListener {
        Map localCache = new ConcurrentHashMap ();

        public static void main(String[] args) { 
                Sample sample = new Sample();
                IMap   map    = Hazelcast.getMap("default"); 

                //Listen for all added/updated/removed entries
                map.addEntryListener(sample, true);  
        }

        public void entryAdded(EntryEvent event) {
             localCache.put(event.getKey(), event.getValue());            
        }

        public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent event) {
             localCache.remove(event.getKey());            
        }

        public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent event) {
             localCache.put(event.getKey(), event.getValue());            
        }
}
```

Comment: java.util.Map does not have a method called " addEntryListener " ..

Comment: you are right. it was supposed to be:
com.hazelcast.core.IMap map = Hazelcast.getMap ("default");

I will actually put an ReplicatedMap implementation into Hazelcast directly to make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered Infinispan - http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/ ? The API is very simple and based on a standard (JSR-107). The usage is also very simple

```
CacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager(
                GlobalConfiguration.getClusteredDefault() );

Cache cache = manager.getCache();

cache.put("key", "value");
```

--Hardy

Comment: Another very promising solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered Terracotta? Might be overkill: http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Data+Caching

There was a JSR in the area of caching a while ago, do any of the following fit the bill: http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions/jcache ?

I personally used FKache a few years ago and it worked well, but I didn't use it in distributed mode.

Is it important that it's a distributed cache with local copies of data? There's also the JavaSpaces stuff if it's shared memory you need...

Comment: I considered using Terracotta and plan to use it as a last resort as it is, as you stated, overkill.

Comment: Not sure I understand the sentiment here.  I'm biased of course - since I work for Terracotta - but using Terracotta to do simple caching is in fact extremely easy and should provide you with excellent performance.

It is as simple as marking a ConcurrentHashMap as clustered and you have a synchronized cache.  See here for an example: http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Recipe?recipe=concurrenthashmap

And if you want/need eviction, you can get that from an add-on library: http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/docs/Cache+Evictor

Comment: My only little problem with Terracotta is that it requires a server to work. It's not 100% P2P. I know I haven't mentioned it in my question, so +1 for the answer :)

Comment: Fair enough - but P2P has a host of issues also.  I am obviously biased towards Terracotta considering I work there, that said, solutions based on UDP, multicast and P2P in my experience never work well in production.  They require switch level and OS level configuration and tuning for any reasonable level of scale, and beyond 4 nodes, P2P breaks down as replicate everywhere doesn't work.  So in the end, for production solutions invariably turn off multicasting, switch to TCP replication, and use the equivalent of a server based topology.  But in dev, they certainly seem nice :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input Taylor. Sadly, as it is often the case in software development, the choice between P2P vs Client/Server is not mine to take :(

I'll let my boss know however. We've used Terracotta on other projects (that did not require P2P) in the past, maybe that'll help ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've used a few technologies in this area, I can highly recommend [JBoss Cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/) as the best choice for what you're trying to do. It uses JGroups as its transport, but provides a higher-level transactional abstraction. Out-of-the-box it gives you a distributed tree-node structure.

edit: Oh, and JBossCache is independent of JBoss Application Server, you can use it in any environment. If anything, it works better outside of JBossAS than it does inside it.

Answer (score 1):

[Memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) has several [Java Clients](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients).

Comment: I am not working on a web server. I suppose that the problem here is the term "cache" which is not really what I'm looking for. I need a shared data structure ;)

Comment: Memcached doesn't have anything to do with web servers.  It is the type of thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My option is [Java Caching System](http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/) from Apache, it has support of TCP Lateral Cache which in my opinion is the feature you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, from the documentation : "[...]The two local caches could potentially have different versions of the same item. Like most caches, this is intended for high get and low put utilization, and this occurrence would hint at improper usage".. Once again I suspect that the term "cache" is probably not the right word to use in my situation. I will need to put data in the "cache" as often as I need to read it.

Answer (score 0):

http://ehcache.org/ is very good and light cache. It can be shared between multiple JVMs.
Internally it can use JGroups.