# Running java server cluster with local up to date cache

Tags: java, performance, redis, cloud, distributed-computing

I need to create a clustered micro-service (means it is a service which runs on different nodes, replicated). This service needs a "super fast" for "GET" operation e.g: when receiving username then responding with a user token. 
this service can be slow on other token operations like save/update/delete.

problems and assumpsions:

- logged in users (which has tokens) can be something like 10,000 - 20,000 users.
- speed: The service needs to be super fast for the "getToken" operation, so I need some way to store it in memory **locally** e.g: HashMap.
- stale: Since there are replicas, I have micro services which also suppose to have the same cache somehow.
- slow: slow operation can be perform when executing token update/delete/save, no problem in that, as long as after update/delete/save, all caches are up to date.

I have started to look at Redis as a buzzword for Caching and also for storing user session, **BUT**, I have found out that people are confused, and doesn't have the right answer for the above problem.
Redis is a Cached database, which means it runs in memory, but it can't used in my case because I am a clusterd service which has replicas of local memory, REDIS can't synchronize my local cache (or is it). Redis can't give me solution for this problem, REDIS driver is not synchronizing my HashMap, although I thought about some pub/sub of Redus to solve this issue, but still, its stale data!

I think  the "super fast" is to use local Java HashMap, and every micro-service on startup will take the Tokens data from some DB (who cares which DB), and, when READ is made, just give data from local memory, but, when update/delete/save made, then send a message to a message queue, and wait for message queue to fan out all messages to the subscribers (other replicas).

I'm not sure if I'm inventing the wheel here, I mean, this is a common problem of distributed cache, is there any other known solution for this? remember, only GET operation need to be fast.

Comment: How much your "super fast" would be? Is it 100ms, 50ms, 10ms or nanoseconds?

Comment: You are trying to re-invent the wheel it seems. To me it sounds like you would get a long way with using Hazelcast[1] with a backing MapStore[2]. This gives a very clean programming model (it would feel like working with a local map). See also Hazelcast's "near cache".

[1]https://hazelcast.org/
[2]https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/distributed-map/mapstore/src/main/java/jdbc/PersonMapStore.java

Comment: Mirten, if I would get along with Hazelcast, I wouldn't post this question, do note, I have researched a lot on my problem, this is a specific issue of packet inspection, and yes, it's need to be "super fast" and not "near cache" there is no reason for me to use "near-cache" when my reads needs to be fast but writes can be slow, I can just use a local memory, can't bit that, I just asked if there is some framework which give just that, with the above exactly situation

Comment: Then I guess you saw this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/982606/980178

Comment: this solution is not consitant, when u use listeners to listen for WRITE events (like pub/sub in Redis), u will get aventual consistancy, and stale data. the reason to make WRITES slow, is to gurentee consistancy, "take your time to update all nodes about the "delete/update/save" , but be very fast when READ.